# Custom Options Not Appearing On Product Frontend on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, frontend, backend

I am required to set custom options on the Magento 1.9 Admin Backend on a product, but the custom options do not appear at all on the product's frontend page on the website, how do I fix this problem? Would I need to edit a Magento file in File Manager on the website for custom options to work? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Backend:

[image: I have already set custom options on a product on the Magento 1.9 Admin Backend]

But the Frontend, however:

[image: Custom Options do not appear at all on the product's frontend page]

Comment: where is your add to cart button?

Comment: The Add To Cart Button appears with the Custom Options, but the Custom Options do not appear at all on the product's frontend page, like I already said.

Comment: Did you checked with default theme ?